# Salesforce cloning and integration

Tags: integration, clone, nonprofit-starter-pack

We have multiple salesforce orgs for multiple non profits. All of them need to have same functionality but different organization. Is there a way to clone all these organization? If I make changes, including Apex and schema, it should reflect on all the orgs. Although we are eligible for 4 free non profit accounts with 10 users each we are not allowed to have all 40 users in a single account. This is the only workaround we can think. All the orgs must have exact copy of data, tasks, custom objects, triggers and workflows.

Comment: The migration tool might be worth looking into. You could at least do deployments identically to all four orgs with a single command.

Answer (score 2):

Using a multi-org model is usually not recommended by implementation partners. They'll note that though the annual cost is lower, the implementation cost is MUCH MUCH higher. If you have a dedicated developer and admin on staff at each org though, you might be able to get away with it.

In general, you're going to want to package up your code (likely as an unmanaged package) from one instance that is the official and blessed metadata provider. All other organizations can then install it. Those other orgs will have the ability to edit their own instance, though, and tracking those upstream changes could be VERY challenging. That's why this isn't recommended.

Similarly, you can use [Salesforce to Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce) to set up data sharing between the orgs (notice, this is completely separate from metadata). S2S has a lot of limitations and caveats, but its the best tool out there. [Organization Sync](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=SA_overview.htm&language=en_US#SA_overview) may also be handy, but it also comes with limits and severe considerations. Talk to your AE for details.

Ultimately, you're going to run into a lot of issues running as a multi-org, especially if you want ALL data to be shared. Look out for RecordType ID issues, field name issues, and more. Be ready for data to be out of sync, and come up with your plan to resolve those issues. This isn't going to be fun. The NPSP isn't built for this one bit.

Answer (score 0):

you can always uses unmanaged package or managed package to deploy/migrate the components.